# MegaRaid LSI raid to mdadm

Tags: raid, mdadm

My MegaRaid controller died and I'm trying to use md to mount the raid, but can't seem to figure it out.

`sudo mdadm --detail --scan` returns:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/ddf0 metadata=ddf UUID=2acf6bbb:f1f23ebd:7da6e057:c1458eb5
ARRAY /dev/md/Storage container=/dev/md/ddf0 member=0 UUID=33ac997c:28b26e9b:1a81c487:a0e6496e
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` returns:

> ```
> Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
> md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid10 sdd[3] sda[2] sdb[1] sdc[0]
>   5859373056 blocks super external:/md127/0 1024K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
>   
> md127 : inactive sdd[3](S) sdc[2](S) sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
>   2320224 blocks super external:ddf
>    
> unused devices: <none>
> ```

`sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md126` returns:

> ```
> /dev/md126:
>      Container : /dev/md/ddf0, member 0
>     Raid Level : raid10
>     Array Size : 5859373056 (5587.93 GiB 6000.00 GB)
>  Used Dev Size : 2929686528 (2793.97 GiB 3000.00 GB)
>   Raid Devices : 4
>  Total Devices : 4
>
>          State : clean 
> Active Devices : 4    Working Devices : 4
> Failed Devices : 0
>  Spare Devices : 0
>
>         Layout : near=2
>     Chunk Size : 1024K
>
> Consistency Policy : resync
>
> Container GUID : 4C534920:20202020:10000079:10009263:4497B5C7:B145AA4D
>               (LSI      06/19/16 08:45:59)
>            Seq : 0000025d
>  Virtual Disks : 1
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>    2       8        0        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda
>    1       8       16        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb
>    0       8       32        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc
>    3       8       48        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd
> ```

`sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md127` returns:

> ```
> /dev/md127:
>        Version : ddf
>     Raid Level : container
>  Total Devices : 4
>
> Working Devices : 4
>
> Container GUID : 4C534920:20202020:10000079:10009263:4497B5C7:B145AA4D
>               (LSI      06/19/16 08:45:59)
>            Seq : 0000025d
>  Virtual Disks : 1
>
>  Member Arrays : /dev/md/Storage
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice
>
>    -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
>    -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
>    -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
>    -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
> ```

I have run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and rebooted and still nothing I have also `sudo mount /dev/m126p1 /Storage` I get no error, but no data shows at /Storage and `lsblk` does not show it being mounted. Any help would be great

Update: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Update: I was able to successfully get /dev/m126p1 to mount to /Storage, turns out I already had a entry for /dev/md0 to mount to /Storage, once I changed that to /dev/md126p1 it mounted fine and I can see my data.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Updated with version, thanks David